# refreshing data grid view doesn't work

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, refresh

I want to refresh data grid view but it doesn't work
i have a Refresh method like this :

```
public void Select() 
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string cs = "server=(local);database=DB_Taxi;trusted_connection=yes;";
    con.ConnectionString = cs;
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver";
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    grid.DataSource = dt;
}
```

and it is on main form.
I want call this function in another form named Add_Driver.
for that I tell it like this in submit button because I get same text box values and after submit them i want to show them in data grid view from database.
I call it like this:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtID.Text != "" || txtName.Text != "" || txtLastName.Text != "" || txtMobile.Text != "" ||
            txtPhone.Text != "" || txtCar.Text != "" || txtGender.Text != "" || txtAddress.Text != "")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string cs = "server=(local);database=DB_Taxi;trusted_connection=yes;";
            con.ConnectionString = cs;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Driver(DriverID,DName,DLastName,DMobile,DAddress,DCar,DGender,DPhone) VALUES(@ID,@Name,@LastName,@Mobile,@Address,@Car,@Gender,@Phone)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car", txtCar.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtGender.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Empty();
            ////////////////////
            Main m = new Main();
            m.Select();
            ////////////////////
            MessageBox.Show("Added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Plese complete the form");                
        }            
    }
```

but data on data grid view doesn't change.
please help!
but when i call this method on the main form it works
but i write like this for main method:

```
Select()
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what's happening?

Comment: Use MVVM pattern it's works better.

Comment: Yes I debug it.But nothing was unusual.

Comment: Try setting Datasource to `null` first and then set the actual source.

Comment: **1)** Main form, with data, opens Form2. **2)** Form2 triggers `btnOK_Click` to populate *a new instance* of Main form. (You now have Main - original data, Form2, Main - new data) **3)** Form2 closes (losing the new instance of Main) - leaving you with just the original Main form and its original data. **TLDR;** Don't populate a new instance of `Main` in your subsequent form. `Main m = new Main()` should instead reference the existing form.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
public void Select() {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string cs = "server=(local);database=DB_Taxi;trusted_connection=yes;";
    con.ConnectionString = cs;
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver";
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();

    //clearing the datasource
    grid.DataSource = null;

    //set the datasource
    grid.DataSource = dt;
}
```